# Jenkins - Can you trigger a stage/step after working hours and only once (not everyday)?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, triggers, cron, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pretty large repository and need to include static analysis, since it takes far too long (about 4 hours) for a normal working day we have a cron set to trigger the build automatically every morning purely to perform the static analysis stage and the way we have it set up it only does the static analysis if there has been a change in the code otherwise the static analysis becomes redundant.

The problem lies with the cron, because it is set every day we are now losing build history as well as artifacts.

I've tried to conditionally set the cron but that didn't seem to work since it should have triggered the build this morning and didn't.

```
triggers {
    cron ( checkBuildStatus() )
}

def checkBuildStatus(){
    if (currentBuild.changeSets.size() > 0){
        return '0 4 * * 1-5 ' 
    }
    else  {
        return ''
    }
}
```

Even if the above implementation worked I'm still not convinced that it would solve my problem of "empty" builds.

Is there a way to trigger a stage/step after working hours and only once (not everyday)?

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! No answers in the question, please. I have rolled back/edited your question and removed the answer. Add the answer in the answer section only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to change my approach and found the best solution. I created a method, it first checks if there has been a change in the code between the current build and the one before it, and also checks that the branch name is 'master'. I then went ahead and checked the day of the week and set the cron to the following day (e.g if the build is on a Monday the cron will be set to Tuesday morning where it will then perform the static analysis stage). Now the cron will only be set if there has been a change in code and always only for the next day (of course until the next week but I'm hoping there will be changes on the master branch at least every week therefore resetting the cron)

```
def setCronTrigger(){
    if (currentBuild.changeSets.size() > 0 && BRANCH_NAME.equals('master')){
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        def day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)
        cron = '* 4 * * ' + day
        return cron
    }
    else {
        return ''
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well we can try to solve that problem in another way.

1. let's create one more job, e.g. cronTrigger. That jobs only triggers external job with static analysis.

> ```
> if (currentBuild.changeSets.size() > 0) {
>     build(job: externalJobName, parameters: []) // run another job
> }
> ```

2. You can keep more build. That possible to changes as well

Comment: My pipeline project is set up with three different stages, one to compile and test, one to cross compile and test and another for static analysis. The main reason for using the cron in the first place was to trigger the build for the static analysis after hours as to not make the build take longer. Now the build is triggered everyday unnecessarily when we only needed it for the static analysis.

Are you saying I would need a separate external pipeline for the static analysis.

Comment: yes. just create one more pipeline.

e.g. you have job staticCodeAnalysis, then you add one more - staticCodeAnalysisCron

and staticCodeAnalysisCron is scheduled job/pipline

Comment: I'm not sure how that would prevent empty/useless builds since the cron will still be scheduled every day. I only need the analysis directly after a build after working hours and then not again until the next build which could be anywhere between 2 days and a week depending on when someone pushes a change

Comment: well. I've get lost a bit. You have to define condition when you don'e need to run code static analysis.  Usually you have to run it for each build. then I don't get why do you need cron at all?

Comment: I run static code analysis for each build, correct. But, as I have said before, I can't run it when I am compiling and testing since the static code analysis takes almost 5 hours to complete making an ordinary build take almost 7 hours. When we make changes to the code we want to make sure nothing has failed so the static analysis can be run separately since statis analysis is only a report and will never fail a build. Therefore I set the cron for the next morning outside of working hours.